# I can't install firebase 5.9.4v

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, npm, npm-install

I am trying to install firebase@5.9.4 with `npm install firebase@5.9.2` but it always give me this error, any suggestions?

> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...socket":"0.11.1","tsl'

If anyone help me I will be grateful

Comment: show whole error log and also the package.json

Comment: This is the whole error

Comment: firebase 7.14.1 is in market you should move with flow update it to the latest and try and alow post your package.json